# CSS Transform Scale of child - parent still occupies same space

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transform

I'm scaling a child div in a parent container using `transform: scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 1)`. 
This scales the child div, but the height initially occupied by the parent div is still the same. This effect can be seen in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XgGGQ/), using the dev console. Is there a way (via css or javascript) to shrink also the parent height?

As the real use case is much more complex I cannot apply a transform scale to the parent div.

Comment: What would be inside the child div? do you need the specified `width` and `height` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript or jquery to add a class to the parent. For example in jQuery:

```
$('.child').parent().addClass('parent');
```

You can then apply your transformation in CSS to the parent container as well.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood the question - I assumed that you "cannot apply a transform scale" as you had no selector. Maybe that's not the reason why?

Comment: Thank for your answer. I cannot apply a transform scale because of other reasons, as the real use case is much more complex.

Comment: It's difficult to say what the best solution would be without seeing the bigger picture. I'm sure there will be a javascript solution at the very least. My first guess would be that you could use javascript to take the height of the child after the transform and then use that variable to set a new height for the parent.